# While debugging VC++ 6.0 application getting unhandled exception error

Tags: visual-c++, exception

I am try to debug an VC++ 6.0 code. My application takes MSWord 2003 document as input and gives the output as MSExcel 2003 format. in that code when its try to save the document it gives an error as

```
 "Unhandled exception in <program_name.exe>(KERNEL32.DLL):0xE06D7363: Microsoft C++ Exception."
```

Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

Hook up a debugger, enable exceptions in the debugger, and see where the exception comes from.
Look at the call stack to see which of your functions calls the 'offending code'.
Check the arguments that your function passes to the called function.

Try to reproduce the problem in a smaller application.  Make it smaller and smaller until you find the cause of the problem.  If you can't make your application any smaller, and you still have the problem, post the code here.